# Selecting txt file from any location with File Chooser in Java

Tags: java, file

I have used the [Sun File Chooser Demo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) to choose files from my desktop or any location.

I have added the following code in the open file action:

```
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
                log.append("Opening: " + file.getName() + "." + newline);
                ReadData rd = new ReadData();  //added by me
                rd.readData(file.getName());   //added by me
            } else {
                log.append("Open command cancelled by user." + newline);
```

ReadData class contains readData method which will take the file name and with BufferedReader will read the contents of the file line by line.

But after choosing the file with file chooser it is not able to open the file from my desktop.If I place the file inside the project folder it is able to open the file without any code change.
What modification in code I need to do so that it can choose and open file from any location?
Thanks

Comment: you are using file name and that is the main issue as posted in all answers. b/c Java input stream looking the file in as you pass the name into the path where you start your application.

Comment: As an aside.  I think most of the methods in the J2SE that accept a `String` that represents a `File` should be deprecated.  If a method needs a `File`, demand a `File` and stop p*ssing about.

Answer (score 4):

You are passing only the file's name, not the complete path, to your `ReadData` class. So, your `ReadData` class is not going to know in which directory the file is - it will try to find it in the current directory (whatever that is at the moment).

Instead of just passing the name of the file, pass the whole path:

```
rd.readData(file.getPath());
```

Better yet, change your `ReadData.readData()` method so that it takes a `File` instead of a `String`, and pass it the `File` object that you get back from the file chooser:

```
rd.readData(file);
```

Answer (score 1):

`getName()` only gets the last segment of the file without any path information.  If the working directory of your Java application isn't the exact directory that holds that file, that won't work.

Why doesn't your `ReadData` just take a file?  All file input mechanisms built into Java will accept a `File` (e.g. `FileInputStream`, `FileReader`).  Otherwise use `getPath()` I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You are only passing the name of the file to the readData() method.

So if your file is stored at C:\Users\JavaBits\Project\Java\file.txt, your readData() method is only getting file.txt so it can't find the file. You should do this:

```
rd.readData(file);
```

This will have the relative path in it.

Answer (score 1):

use file object to open inputstream instead using its name. such as:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileInputStream(file));
```

modify your method readData to accept File object instead String, and use this object to open BufferedReader.